# Select Random 10 documents from mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am learning node and mongo and currently working on a simple server which will just fetch 10 random documents from mongodb and send them as response on receiving a get request. My next aim is to create a single page which will display these 10 records in a html page with some basic styling. The page also has a next button which will fetch another 10 random records from the database. The problem is how can I make sure that the same records are not fetched twice in this process?

Comment: this question is not a duplicate because it asks how to avoid querying the same elements...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To pick `10` random documents you can use [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) pipeline stage.

```
let randomDocs = db.col.aggregate(
    [ { $sample: { size: 10 } } ]
)
```

If you want to make sure that next `$sample` call will not return the same documents you need to make it stateful meaning that you should filter out the documents that were returned in previous call:

```
db.col.aggregate(
    [
        { $match: { _id: { $nin: randomDocs.map(doc => doc._id) } } },
        { $sample: { size: 10 } } 
    ]
)
```

Comment: So you mean I should keep all the previously returned random docs in an array? Will that be an efficient way?

Comment: You should keep them somewhere if you want to gurantee that those will not be randomly picked again